# Matching two coordinates in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, compare, java.util.scanner

I have this program and I'm reading a line of x and y coordinates and have to find the longest line of co-linear points. I'm reading them in and storing all the xCoordinates in an ArrayList and all the yCoordinates in another list. I need to compare the slopes and print out the longest line. I have the slopes calculated but can't figure out how to compare them to each other. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> xCoord = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> yCoord = new ArrayList<Double>();
        //      double xCoord[] = null;
        //      double yCoord[] = null;
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0; 
        double slope = 0;
        double slope2 = 0;


        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            //grabs x and y coordinate
            xCoord.add(scanner.nextDouble());
            yCoord.add(scanner.nextDouble());

            //formatting
            if(i == 0) {
                System.out.println(" X  Y");
                System.out.println(" -  -");
            }
            System.out.print(xCoord.get(i) + " ");
            System.out.print(yCoord.get(i));
            System.out.print("\n");


            //ending case
            if((i > 0) && (xCoord.get(i).equals(xCoord.get(i-1)) && yCoord.get(i).equals(yCoord.get(i-1)))) {
                System.out.println("Hey, they matched");
                break;
            }


            if(i > 0) {
                slope = (xCoord.get(i-1) - xCoord.get(i))/(yCoord.get(i-1) - yCoord.get(i));
                System.out.println("Slope: " + slope);
            }


            i+=1;
        }




    }

}
```

The program terminates when you get two of the same x,y coordinates (I have that working).

Comment: Longest line? Use distance formula to get the length of line

Comment: You mean d = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)?
How do I compare the two distances in the loop?

Comment: Are you trying to find the longest line formed by any co-linear points within given x and y? Are you? Because code that you've shown does not do that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, I did some minor (?) modifications and also added some new code to get the longest points on a line

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;
public class CollinearPoints {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
        List<Slope> slopes = new ArrayList<Slope>();
        int i = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            // grabs x and y coordinate
            Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(scanner.nextDouble(), scanner.nextDouble());

            // formatting
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.println(" X  Y");
                System.out.println(" -  -");
            }
            System.out.print(coordinate.getX() + " ");
            System.out.print(coordinate.getY());
            System.out.print("\n");

            // ending case
            if ((i > 0)
                    && (coordinate.getX() == coordinates.get(i-1).getX() && 
                            coordinate.getY() == coordinates.get(i-1).getY())) {
                System.out.println("Hey, they matched");
                break;
            }
            coordinates.add(coordinate);
            i += 1;
        }
        /* Calculate slopes between all the points */
        for(i =0; i < coordinates.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < coordinates.size(); j++){
                Coordinate coordinate1 = coordinates.get(i);
                Coordinate coordinate2 = coordinates.get(j);
                double slope = getSlope(coordinate1, coordinate2);
                slopes.add(new Slope(coordinate1, coordinate2, slope));
            }
        }
        /* Calculate slope counts (to know which one occurs max times) */
        Map<String, Double> slopeCountsMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        for(Slope slope : slopes){
            slopeCountsMap.put(String.valueOf(slope.getSlope()), Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(getMatchingSlopeCount(slope.getSlope(), slopes))));
        }
        /* Sort the slope :: slope-count map */
        ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(slopeCountsMap);
        TreeMap<String,Double> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,Double>(bvc);
        sorted_map.putAll(slopeCountsMap);

        /* get the maximum occurring slope */
        double maxSlope = Double.parseDouble(sorted_map.firstKey());

        /* Collect the list of co-ordinates having the max occurring slope and which are collinear */
        List<Coordinate> colinearPoints = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
        for(Slope slope : slopes){
            if(maxSlope == slope.getSlope()){
                if(colinearPoints.size() < 2){
                    if(!colinearPoints.contains(slope.getCoordinate1())){
                        colinearPoints.add(slope.getCoordinate1());
                    }
                    if(!colinearPoints.contains(slope.getCoordinate2())){
                        colinearPoints.add(slope.getCoordinate2());
                    }
                } else {
                    if(colinearPoints.contains(slope.getCoordinate1()) &&
                            !colinearPoints.contains(slope.getCoordinate2())){
                        colinearPoints.add(slope.getCoordinate2());
                    } else if(colinearPoints.contains(slope.getCoordinate2()) &&
                            !colinearPoints.contains(slope.getCoordinate1())){
                        colinearPoints.add(slope.getCoordinate1());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Colinear points: ");
        System.out.println(colinearPoints);
    }

    private static int getMatchingSlopeCount(double slope, List<Slope> slopes){
        int count = 0;
        for(Slope slope2 : slopes){
            if(slope == slope2.getSlope()){
                count ++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    /* Calculate slope between two points */
    private static double getSlope(Coordinate coordinate1, Coordinate coordinate2){
        return ((coordinate2.getY() - coordinate1.getY()) / (coordinate2.getX() - coordinate1.getX()));
    }
}
/* Class to hold co-ordinates */
class Coordinate {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Coordinate() {
    }
    public Coordinate(double x, double y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (((Coordinate)o).getX() == this.getX() && ((Coordinate)o).getY() == this.getY());
    }
}
/* Class to hold slope between two points */
class Slope {
    private Coordinate coordinate1;
    private Coordinate coordinate2;
    private double slope;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + coordinate1.getX() + "," + coordinate1.getY() + ")(" + coordinate2.getX() + "," + coordinate2.getY() + ")";
    }
    public double getSlope() {
        return slope;
    }
    public void setSlope(double slope) {
        this.slope = slope;
    }
    public Coordinate getCoordinate1() {
        return coordinate1;
    }
    public void setCoordinate1(Coordinate coordinate1) {
        this.coordinate1 = coordinate1;
    }
    public Coordinate getCoordinate2() {
        return coordinate2;
    }
    public void setCoordinate2(Coordinate coordinate2) {
        this.coordinate2 = coordinate2;
    }
    public Slope() {
    }
    public Slope(Coordinate coordinate1, Coordinate coordinate2, double slope) {
        super();
        this.coordinate1 = coordinate1;
        this.coordinate2 = coordinate2;
        this.slope = slope;
    }
}
/* Comparator to sort the map */
class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    Map<String, Double> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Start by declaring a variable to hold the longest line found so far. Say longestSoFar. Set this to a small number such as 0 since you will not get any lines that are shorter than 0. In the loop when you find the length of a line just compare it to longestSoFar.

```
  if(lengthOfCurrentLine > longestSoFar){
         longestSoFar = lengthOfCurrentLine;
  }
```

And of course you will keep the points that gave the longest line so far.

At the end of the loop whatever is stored in that variable is your answer.

Comment: Not an answer. He has asked how he can use slope values to find the longest line.